# Constrain unique value between multiple tables

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017

I have a database where there's one base table that is extended (by foreign keying) by other tables. Something like this:

[image]

I've been assigned a task where I have to do the following check before inserting an "Animal":

- Animals Id must be UNIQUE
- (Thus) Fishes Id must be UNIQUE
- There may be ZERO OR MORE "dead" (Alive = False) Fishes for a specific FishEspecieId
- There may be ZERO OR ONE "alive" (Alive = True) Fish for a specific FishEspecieId

---

The task suggested that I do it on API insert method, something like this (pseudo-code):

```
Method Insert(Fish fish)
    Fish[] fishes = DB.GetAll<Fish>()

    if (fishes.Any(f => f.FishEspecieId == fish.FishEspecieId f.Animal.Alive))
        throw "Only one alive fish allowed"

    Animal animal = DB.Insert<Animal>({alive: true})
    DB.Insert({Id: animal.Id, ...})
```

I'm actually going to, indeed, do a check in the API. However, I think it's a good idea to also ensure the rules on the DB side.

How may I do this in SQL Server? And is this indeed a good idea or should I keep only in the backend side?

---

**Ps.** This is only a MRE. I know that if this was my database I should make it a single table. If that was the case, I would simply use `UNIQUE(FishEspecieId) WHERE (Alive = 1)`. In my case, however, I have many tables that extends "Animal", or something like this.

Comment: A partial/filtered UNIQUE constraint should do what you want (if Alive was in table Fish): `UNIQUE (FishEspecieId, Id) WHERE (Alive = 1)`. What is the datatype of column `Alive`?

Comment: Is `Fish.ID` a `Foreign Key` to `Animal.ID`?

Comment: @KirkSaunders Yes, both PK and FK to `Animal.Id`.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ Bit (the SQL Server boolean-like type)

Comment: Just to complement, I want to constrain the creation of Animal based on these conditions, and not the opposite. Fish is dependent on Animal because of it's FK, so if I constain Animal, I constrain both (and also every other "Animal" that will extend Animal table).

Comment: Is there anything on the `Animal` table that tells us this is a `Fish`?  Or is the only way to tell by `JOIN`ing `Animal` and `Fish` together?

Comment: @KirkSaunders No, only the FK of Fish to Animal tells this relation. To "build" the full data, I usually join Animal+Fish, Animal+Dog, Animal+Bird etc

Comment: Ok.  Presumably you would also need to make sure that `Animal.ID` of 5 (for example) only shows in one of the `"SUB" Animal` tables (`Bird`, `Dog`, `Fish`, etc..)  Correct?

Comment: @KirkSaunders No exactly... this is not the problem here. Basically I want to ensure something like `UNIQUE(Fish.FishEspecieId) WHERE (Animal.Alive = 1)`, when inserting a Animal. Of course I can't use UNIQUE with multiple tables, but this is the idea.

Example: I have a Fish with FishEspecieId of 1. I may only insert an Animal that will in the future have a Fish associetade with it and has FishEspecieId of 1 if this first Fish is related with an Animal that is not Alive. If it's Alive, the UNIQUE constraint fails.

Comment: In some sense, the constraint would have to know the FishEspecieId beforehand and the Animal type (Fish, for example). The later can be easily known with sequential JOINS, like I already did. However, the first one is what is bothering me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98546/discussion-between-kirk-saunders-and-mateus-felipe).

Comment: @MateusFelipe, can you please join me in the discussion room i opened up (link is in my previous comment). I still have some more questions and it will be better to do all of that in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Talking with Mateus in the discussion he mentioned that he wants to avoid an insert onto the `Animal` table in this kind of instance if at all possible.  As he and I discussed it is difficult since all conditions do not live in the same place.

Using a `Trigger` you should be able to remove the `Animal` table record for an instance where an `Insert` into `Fish` fails this condition.  You will need conditions for both `Insert` and `Update` since we most likely won't want to delete the `Animal` table record via the `Trigger` on `Updates`.

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.FishAliveInsert ON dbo.Fish
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS
    (
        SELECT 1
        FROM INSERTED I
            INNER JOIN Fish F
                ON F.FishEspecieId = I.FishEspecieId
            INNER JOIN Animal A
                ON F.ID = A.ID
        WHERE A.IsAlive = 1
    )
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR ('This Fish cannot be added because a Fish of this FishEspecieId already exists and is Alive.', 16, 1);
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION; --stops the Insert

        DELETE FROM Animal WHERE ID = (SELECT ID FROM INSERTED) --I am a little less confident in the correct syntax here.  

        RETURN 
    END
END

CREATE TRIGGER dbo.FishAliveUpdate ON dbo.Fish
AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS
    (
        SELECT 1
        FROM INSERTED I
            INNER JOIN Fish F
                ON F.FishEspecieId = I.FishEspecieId
            INNER JOIN Animal A
                ON F.ID = A.ID
        WHERE A.IsAlive = 1
    )
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR ('This Fish cannot be updated because a Fish of this FishEspecieId already exists and is Alive.', 16, 1);
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION; --stops the Insert        
        RETURN 
    END
END
```

One piece of this you will still need to handle is what if an `Animal` record is added but nothing an a given `Sub-Animal` table?

I think that you could create a simple SQL Agent Job that Deletes records in the `Animal` table which don't exist in all the various `Sub-Animal` tables, and that `Animal` table record is of a certain age (5 minutes old, 10 minutes old, etc...).  You would need to have a column that captures when the `Animal` record was added/last modified, but outside of that you should be good to go.

You could use the already proven answer given by David Browne and just implement this idea of a `SQL Agent Job` to do an `Animal` Table cleanup after the fact.  He probably recommended it because it performs better or uses less resources than a `Trigger` so that may very well be the way to go.

Answer (score 4):

You can enforce this with an Indexed View (or a trigger, of course).  EG

```
create table Animal(Id int primary key, Alive bit)

create table Fish(Id int primary key references Animal, FishEspecieId int)

go
create or alter view vFish_Alive
with schemabinding
as
select f.Id, f.FishEspecieId, a.Alive
from dbo.Fish f
join dbo.Animal a
  on f.Id = a.Id 
where a.Alive = 1

 go

 create unique clustered index pk_vFish_Alive on vFish_Alive(FishEspecieId)

 go
 insert into Animal(id,alive) values (1,1),(2,1)

insert into Fish(id,FishEspecieId) values (1,1)

insert into Fish(id,FishEspecieId) values (2,1)
--Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.vFish_Alive' with unique index 'pk_vFish_Alive'. The duplicate key value is (1).
```

Comment: Actually, I want to constrain Animal insert, and not Fish insert.